# How read/write external files on Android 11(API 30)

Tags: android, xamarin

When I run my APP and the APP tries read a pdf file, i get the error:

> File is corrupt or not exist.

I have this

```
[Obsolete]
public async Task<string> SaveFileToDisk(string fileName, byte[] bytes)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(_rootDir))
         Directory.CreateDirectory(_rootDir);

    var filePath = Path.Combine(_rootDir, fileName);

    File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);

    return filePath;
}
```

The error happens in the line below

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(_rootDir);
```

I know that Android 11 doesn't work with External Storage.
I enabled

**ReadExternalStorage, WriteExternalStorage, ManageExternalStorage**

this last can be a problem with Play Store correct?

How can I solve this? How can i read and write files using Android 11?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage for what has changed in Android 11.

Comment: Edit it in an ordinary text editor? I know nothing about Mac software.

Comment: How do i use FORCE_ENABLED_STORAGE? I search it into Manifest file and i didn't find it.

Comment: What do you mean by `FORCE_ENABLED_STORAGE`? Are you talking about `FORCE_ENABLE_SCOPED_STORAGE`? That's not something you set in your manifest. It's a setting you toggle either in the phone's developer options or through adb. See https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/test-debug#toggle

Comment: @Michel, yes, you are sure. I changed for local dir(Download), the app was trying to create a new dir and this operation is not possible. My code was: `private readonly string _rootDir = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, "pdfjs");` so it was trying to create pdfjs then i changed by Download and this way it worked.